# Public Access Lookup failing

Tags: xpages

The ACL of my database has Anonymous set to No Access with Read Public documents set.   I have an Xpage that I set to Public Access. The page displays fine, without having to login,  with the exception that the  page that is supposed to display a message  based on a field in a document that is looked up from a view.  The lookup fails if public access is turned on for the xPage.  If I turn Public Access off for the xPage then I am of course asked to log in to display the page but the message displays on the page.

Here is the formula that I am using.   I have modfied it a bit to help troubleshoot this issue.  With Public Access for the xPage set, the code displays a "4" (document not found in the view).

```
var vw:NotesView = database.getView("Setup");
var doc:NotesDocument = vw.getDocumentByKey("Setup",true);
if (doc != null)
{
try
{
    return "1"+doc.getFirstItem("PasswordChangeSuccess").getMIMEEntity().getContentAsText();
}
catch (e)
{   try
    {
        return "2"+doc.getFirstItem("PasswordChangeSuccess").getText();
    }
    catch (e)
    {

        return "3";     
    }

}
}
else return "4";
```

I have Public Access set for both the Setup view and the form that displays the Setup view.  The PasswordChangeSuccess field is a richtext /MIME field.

I also tried placing a $PublicAccess on the form with no luck.  Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Please verify that the form itself has no acl defined and the data does have the correct values in the reader/authors fields

Comment: Does your document have a *$PublicAccess* field?

Comment: @jjbsomhorst - Form is  set to All Readers and Above.  No special Security.

Comment: @Sven - Look at the last line of my post.

Comment: @BruceStemplewski: I have read your last line. You are talking about the form, I was talking about the document stored in your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  While the $PublicAccess field was on the form it was not being computed.   Everything seems to be working now.

Comment: Ol' trap for XPages. The fact that you have something in the form only becomes relevant if you set the dataSource to compute with the form. I don't use forms much anymore

Answer (score 1):

e.message gives you the error message, add it to your output. My bet is on lack of access. Try this:

```
    var vw:NotesView = database.getView("Setup");
    if (vw == null ) {
        print("Failed to get the view");
        return "NULL view encountered";
    }
    print("View is valid");

    var doc:NotesDocument = vw.getDocumentByKey("Setup",true);

   if (doc == null) {
      print("Doc could not be obtained");
      return("Doc could not be obtained");
   }

   // Only here the fun starts!

  try {
       return "1"+doc.getFirstItem("PasswordChangeSuccess").getMIMEEntity().getContentAsText();
  } catch (e) {
    print("MIME failed:" +e.message);
    try {
         return "2"+doc.getFirstItem("PasswordChangeSuccess").getText();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
      return e.message;     
    }

 }
 // If you got here, what happened?
 return("Miracle");
```

You also should drop you Java/C formatting preference. In JavaScript line endings have significance. so

```
 function bla()
 {

 }
```

gets processed differently from

```
 function bla() {

 }
```

at least there's an extra **does that line ending require an auto-inserted semicolon** processing step. In Java/C it is a matter of coding taste (and up to you). In JavaScript it impacts processing.

Comment: I get Doc could not be obtained displayed just as I mentioned in my post.   I have related follow up information that I will be putting in another post.